# Automatically logon to a website through vb/asp code bypassing the logon dialog

Tags: asp.net, windows, vb.net, authentication, iis

I have a website hosted by Network Solutions.  I have an asp.net website using vb.net and this uses an SQL Server database. I am maintaining a user list internally and controlling what content is seem based on whether or not a person is logged in. This runs on a Windows server and uses IIS.

The problem is I cannot control someone viewing a jpg or pdf file if they know the url to get to it directly.  In order to do this, I used Network Solutions password protection utility to to allow access.  It appears that its created user privileges to that folder and IIS pops up the login dialog in order to view these file. I'm assuming that a user is created in AD to do this but not sure. That all work good with a manual login.

What I want is to be able to login automatically once my user is validated so that they don't have to log in twice to see the files within the restricted folder.

Example: joeblow logs in through my authentication routine. The path to the jpg and pdf files he needs to see is protected and only the user "jondoe" with password "XYZ" can see it. I want to hard code a login with "jondoe" and "XYZ" as long as joeblow (or anyone else) is logged on.

If there may be another solution to this I'd be grateful as well.

Comment: Do not offer links to the physical files and images. Instead, create an ASP page that reads the files and stream them to the user. This way, the user will not have the URL of the actual files and you have a full control over who accesses what. The files should reside in a protected folder outside the virtual directory, so only ASP can access. But maybe this is not possible with some shared hosting, in which case you'll need to secure the folder in another way.

Comment: Also look into the `location` setting in web.config to see if that helps at all.